# dont run app with open-cv in xcode 7?

Tags: ios, opencv, bitcode

I install opencv how pods, and when i run app in my ios devise i have this issue.

> opencv2.framework/opencv2(cap_ios_photo_camera.o)' does not contain 
>   bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the build settings for your App Target, search for "Bitcode" and set Bitcode Enabled to NO.

---

Although I recommend you get the framework vendor to supply a Bitcode enabled version

Comment: Maybe someone should be, that it helped: [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4877)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the "Bitcode" as answered by @liamnichols.

But it is strongly recommended that you must use the frameworks with bitcode enabled. I suggest you to re-create the Opencv framework with bitcode enabled.

Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32710441/3483774), It'll help you creating opencv framework.