# Getting issue on terminal command while creating opencv2.framework

Tags: python, ios, python-2.7, opencv, terminal

I was facing some issues with opencv2.framework in iOS related to bitcode. While searching on the internet, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32710441/3483774) regarding creating the opencv2.framework with bitcode support enabled.

First 3 steps run successfully but on 4th step, i am facing some issue. I dont know whether these are issues regarding to python or something else. Kindly help me. Here are the logs.

[image]

Comment: Hi I am Yan from the post you referred to. Did you try compiling OpenCV without modifying any switches? If you can, then that's the problem of bitcode. But if you still can't, that means you don't have some dependencies installed. From the error message, it seems that the compilation script cannot find some executable files.

Comment: @grapeot Thanks Yan. I think its issue related to python or some other dependencies. Well I am not very good at python. It'll be great if you could please provide me the opencv2.framework with bitcode enabled. You can refer me some link where i can download or it would be better if you could send me zip file.
Thanks..

Comment: It's actually in the post you referred to. :) In the first paragraph, there are two Dropbox links.

Comment: @grapeot Yeah found the same. I am so dumb, how can i missed that. Thanks a lot buddy..

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue. My solution is that:

1. Check cmake has been installed. If not, use home brew to install cmake: `brew install cmake`.
2. Then run `python ../bulid_framework.py <your_save_dic>`

Good luck.